# How to create primeng p-dataTable from JSON structure?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to do it. I do not understand how to implement the items field from next JSON.

```
[
      {
        index: number,
        projectName?: string,

        items: [{ 
        hours: number,
        notes: string,
      },
        {
        index: number,
        projectName?: string,
        items: [{ 
        hours: number,
        notes: string,
      }
//.................
   ]
```

P.S. I use Angular 2.

Comment: [
      {
        index: number,
        projectName?: string,

        items: [{ 
        hours: number,
        notes: string,]
      },
        {
        index: number,
        projectName?: string,
        items: [{ 
        hours: number,
        notes: string,
      }
//.................
   ]

Comment: Your question is not clear. please add more detail, error etc